# Selecting Rows with one column or Columns with NULL value when even one have value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table where i wanted to select a row even if any of the column 1 thought to column 4 have a NOT NULL value and the the other have NULL value in ORACLE

If my data is like below

```
          col1    col2    col3    col4
row1      1       null    null    null
row2      null    2       null    null
row3      null    null    3       null
row4      null    null    null    level1
row5      11      22      33      level2
row6      11      null    33      level2
row7      null    null    null    null
```

I am expecting the output as below

```
          col1    col2    col3    col4
row1      1       null    null    null
row2      null    2       null    null
row3      null    null    3       null
row4      null    null    null    level1
row6      11      null    33      level2
```

I have a very huge table and i don't have index on any of these column and bit worried to use a query something like below.

```
select * from table_name 
   where col1 <> null and col2 = null and col3 = null and col4 = null
   or col1 = null and col2 <> null and col3 = null and col4 = null
    ...
```

Is there any better way to write this in ORACLE sql.?

Comment: Do your rows have an `id` column of some kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either the `GREATEST` or `LEAST` function here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col4) IS NULL;
```

The above call to `GREATEST` would only be `NULL` if at least one of the four columns have a `NULL` value.

If you want to also ensure that a given row has at least one non `NULL` value, then add a condition for that to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    GREATEST(col1, col2, col3, col4) IS NULL AND
    COALESCE(col1, col2, col3, col4) IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: But this would also return null if all fields are null which is not what the OP asked if I'm not  mistaken

Comment: @vc74 I added a condition for that, should the OP also have this requirement.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen this worked and this is what i was looking for. Thanks again!

Comment: Still unclear to me what should happen with only null rows but since he/she accepted your answer...

Comment: @vc74 if all columns are NULL then it can be ignored, i have updated the question to reflect the same!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       > 0;
```

or, just:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ( col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL OR col4 IS NULL );
```

Or if you want to exclude rows that are entirely `NULL`s then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN col2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + CASE WHEN col4 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       BETWEEN 1 AND 3;
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  ( col1 IS NULL OR col2 IS NULL OR col3 IS NULL OR col4 IS NULL )
AND    NOT ( col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL AND col3 IS NULL AND col4 IS NULL );
```

If you create an index on the four columns:

```sql
CREATE INDEX table_name__idx ON table_name ( col1, col2, col3, col4 );
```

Then the bottom query can be performed as an `INDEX FULL SCAN` as shown by the explain plan:

> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                          |
> | :----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 1211442363                                                                |
> |                                                                                            |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       |
> | | Id  | Operation        | Name            | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |       |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT |                 |     6 |    60 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |
> | |*  1 |  INDEX FULL SCAN | TABLE_NAME__IDX |     6 |    60 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |
> | ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=745bfc4fe59c7cf88f704e6c53c7c532)*

Using functions (such as `CASE` or `GREATEST`) would prevent Oracle from using an index.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where col1 is null or col2 is null or col3 is null or col4 is null;
```

Note that `= null` and `<> null` make no sense in SQL.  Almost any comparison to `null` returns `null` -- which is treated as "false" in `where` clauses and `case` expressions.  That is why SQL provides the special operators `is null` and `is not null`.